# Twilio voice api

Tags: api, twilio, voice

I am developing a server to receive incoming call and then connect the user A to use B by dialing number while on call. I want to know it this code is correct? and as User B receive a call it shows User A's contact number, will User A will be charged for the call or my Twilio account?

```
app.get('/call', async (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  twiml.dial('USER_B_NUMBER');
  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple events going on in this scenario. For once, user A will be charged their normal rate (based on their carrier).

[Twilio charges](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132367-How-Much-am-I-Charged-for-Call-Forwarding-with-Twilio-):

> For call forwarding applications, you will be creating two legs for each conversation.
>
> An inbound leg from the caller to your Twilio number.
> An outbound leg from Twilio to the number you are forwarding the call to.
> Each leg is billed separately to your Twilio project on a per-minute basis. Each call is also rounded up to the closest minute.

Comment: Thanks for response! 
Basically I am looking to setup back server that if User A (in USA) calls my Twilio number, I want to connect that call to User B(In Canada).

User A might get charged for outgoing call if they are calling Twilio number, but I do not want to have User A charged for calling User B as international call.

Comment: That should work if the Twilio number is a US number.